# Change main properties of map composer from cache to render from Python Console

Tags: pyqgis, print-composer, qgis-python-console

I'm trying to print out a map from Python console. The issue is that when I add a layer to the map composer, the property of the map is set to cache. However, I want to change it to render so that the map would look less blurry.

Below is my code to add a layer to the map composer:

```
map_settings = iface.mapCanvas().mapSettings()
c = QgsComposition(map_settings)

view = iface.createNewComposer()
view.setComposition(c)

composerMap = QgsComposerMap(c, 10 ,10, 160, 20)
composerMap.setBackgroundEnabled(True)

rect = QgsRectangle(map_settings.fullExtent())
composerMap.setNewExtent(rect)
composerMap.updateItem()
c.addComposerMap(composerMap)
```

I am wondering if there is any way to set the main property of map as render instead of cache from Python console.

Answer (score 1):

You could set it using [QgsComposerMap::setPreviewMode()](https://qgis.org/api/2.18/classQgsComposerMap.html#ac9e81255a8b369395559b5c0c2336962):

```
composerMap.setPreviewMode(0)
# 0 = cache
# 1 = render
# 2 = rectangle
```

Comment: @ryurruuggbbyy - Most welcome, glad it helped :)